# Bayesian Inference for Binomial Distribution with changing mean

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, moving-average

Say I have a long time series of values in the form of 0 or 1 which I believe to be outcomes of a binomial distribution, but where the probability of success $p$ can change (but is expected to change gradually) over time. For example we might have 10,000 outcomes where at the start $p$ was equal to 0.3, and at the end it had shifted to 0.4 (along some path).

How would I best go about estimating $p$ at each trial given the data available and what assumptions would I need to make?

Intuitively I would want to use some sort of weights for the outcomes estimating the mean, like Exponentially Weighted Moving Average, to reflect the fact that it's changing over time. I think with a frequentist approach this might already be sufficient, but I'm not sure how to cast this in a Bayesian framework. In particular the updating of the posterior seems like it would be problematic.

I also had the idea of assigning some dynamic to the evolution of $p$, e.g. at each step it is allowed to remain the same, or increase/decrease slightly, and then using some maximum likelihood method of finding the most likely path that $p$ took given the data. I believe this might be doable with some Sequential Importance Sampling procedures, but I'm not sure how sound the idea itself is.

Would appreciate any suggestions regarding this.

Comment: You need a time-series model. Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197084/binary-time-series or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15068/forecasting-binary-time-series or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201008/modelling-auto-correlated-binary-time-series , any of those could be expressed as a Bayesian model using probabilistic programming software.

Comment: @Tim These threads seem to have to do with forecasting, are you sure this is what I'm looking for? My problem is more concerned with estimating a hidden parameter driving data.

Comment: They discuss models for time-series. There are other models possible, the point is you need a time-series model.